# Cookie: задать и проверить

Tags: php, cookie

Сайт:

**site.com**

1. folder

   - index.php
   - one.php
   - two.php
2. index.php

Собственно, задача в том, чтобы путь пользователя был `folder/index.php -> folder/one.php -> folder/two.php` без возможности перейти от folder/index.php к folder/two.php минуя folder/one.php. Решил реализовать это через куки.

---

Задаю куку при нажатии кнопку "submit" на folder/index.php на 5 минут:

```
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) SetCookie("name_started","Started",time()+300);
```

Затем, если на folder/one.php нажимается кнопка "submit" и есть первая кука, задается кука "name_two" также на 5 минут. Если первой куки нет, редирект на index.php:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['name_started']) && isset($_GET['submit'])) SetCookie("name_two","Two",time()+300);
if (!isset($_COOKIE['name_started'])) exit(redirect("../folder/"));
```

И аналогично на two.php.

---

Проблема в том, что при нажатии кнопки "submit" на folder/index.php, я перехожу на folder/one.php и меня редиректит на folder/index.php, будто кука не сохранялась. В браузере прием куки разрешен.

Comment: А вы проверяли, ставится ли вообще куки?

Comment: Через echo вывод есть, но в браузер ничего не принимается. Пробовал и оперу, и хром

Comment: Поправка - echo пустует

Comment: куки ставятся, проверяли?

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick, в настройках браузера нужных куки не встретил.

Comment: а так стоп. Как у вас экшены прописаны в форме. Там где устанавливается 1 кука экшн на index.php или на one.php ?

Comment: name="submit" на кнопке есть?

Comment: Может `$_GET['submit']` пусто, чаще всего формы в `$_POST`

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick, `<button class="btn btn-primary btn-cons m-t-10" type="submit" name="submit">Далее</button>` , экшн на one.php
@Masiama замена на $_POST не помогла

Comment: Вот теперь смотрите. Вы ставите куку в index.php, а сабмит идёт на one.php. Из этого следует то, что index.php не отрабатывает, соответственно и кука  не ставиться

Comment: Как же тогда закрыть возможность перехода сразу на one.php, если кука не обрабатывается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема вся в том, что не вызывается index.php в action.

Допустим у нас есть шаги регистрации:
1.php - попадаем всегда
2.php - если есть кука из 1.php
3.php - Если есть куки  2.php

реализация должна быть примерно такой:

1.php:

```
 <?php

   if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {

     setcookie("name_started","Started",time()+300);

      header( 'Location: http://test.dev/2.php' ); //если всё ок, то идём в 2.php
   }
 ?>

 <form action="1.php">
     <p>1</p>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send1"/>
 </form>
```

2.php:

```
<?php

   if (isset($_COOKIE['name_started']) && isset($_GET['submit'])) {

       setcookie("name_two","Two",time()+300);

       header( 'Location: http://test.dev/3.php' );  //если всё ок идём в 3.php
   } else if(!isset($_COOKIE['name_started'])) {
       header( 'Location: http://test.dev/1.php' ); //если нету куки, то идём в 1.php
   }
?>

<form action="2.php"> 
    <p>2</p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send2"/>
</form>
```

3.php:

```
<?php


   if ( isset($_COOKIE['name_two']) && isset($_GET['submit'])) {

       setcookie("name_three","Three",time()+300);

       die('success');
   } else if(!isset($_COOKIE['name_two'])) {
       header( 'Location: http://test.dev/2.php' ); //если нет второй куки идём в 2.php, а если нет и первой, то в 2.php есть проверка на первую кук и тогда она редиректит на 1.php
   }
?>

<form action="3.php">
<p>3</p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send3"/>
</form>
```

Вот как то так оно должно работать на куках